# ASP.NET, refresh dropdownlist2 when dropdownlist1 selection changes?

Tags: asp.net

I have two databound dropdownlist controls. The first one (dropdownlist1) pulls directly from a table. The second one (dropdownlist2) also pulls from a table, but uses the selected value from dropdownlist1 in it's WHERE clause.

How do I update/refresh dropdownlist2 after the user makes a selection in dropdownlist1? (Using VB if done by code)

I've tried setting the "Auto Postback" property of dropdownlist1 to "true" and ultimately, this approach works. The only problem is, if I keep changing the selection in dropdownlist1, the selections available in dropdownlist2 are duplicated.

Both dropdownlist controls are contained within a CreateUserWizard control using template. I've tried using FindControl and then DataBind() on dropdownlist2 from the SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdownlist1, but no change occurs after a selection is made in dropdownlist1.

Any ideas?

**SelectedIndexChanged Event**

```
Protected Sub AssignedManager_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("AssignedSupervisor").DataBind()
End Sub
```

*** Above, AssignedManager is the first dropdownlist and AssignedSupervisor is the second dropdownlist ***

Comment: can you plz post your `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: You can play with AppendDataBoundItems or viewstate properties for your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub AssignedManager_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
    CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("AssignedSupervisor").DataSource
     = GetDataSource(Ctype(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstDropDownID"),Dropdownlist).SelectedValue)

    CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("AssignedSupervisor").DataBind()
End Sub

Protected function GetDataSource(string id) as DataTable
    'This function should return datatable based on the value (id) from the first dropdownlist
End Function
```